# JQuery to detect both ctrlKey and mouse click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JQuery, so I don't know much of the logic. I'm using it to find out which index of textarea I clicked while holding the CtrlKey.
However how do I assign a function on a combination of onclick and a keyboard event.

```
//What I have tried:
//textarea is the object where I want to detect both ctrlKey and mouse click
$(textarea).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.ctrlKey){
        $(textarea).click(function(event){
            console.log("catched")
        })
    }
})
```

The above method does work, however It does so thrice, i.e.the console.log occurs thrice, so is there a way to make this catch it once.
also it somehow also occurs when not pressing the ctrl key.

Comment: Please share some code, what you tried, etc.

Comment: sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of small mistakes here, but you had the right idea :)

First off, it doesn't really make sense to stack the event handlers the way you have done - I get what you're thinking logically but in reality JS doesn't work that way. What you've actually said is this:

"If the user presses a key down in this textarea, and if their control key is down, add an event listener to this textarea that detects for clicks, and logs `catched` to the console".

What you really want is this:

```js
$("#txtarea").click((e)=>{
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    console.log("Control + Click!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
```

The `ctrlKey` property is exposed to all events, not just the keypresses.

If it were not though, (say you wanted <kbd>A</kbd> + Click), you would have a `keydown` event which sets global variable `aDown` to `true`, a `keyup` event which sets the `aDown` variable to `false`, and a click event which has an `if` statement in it which only works if `aDown` is true. This is shown below:

```js
let aDown = false;

$("#txtarea").keydown((e)=>{
  aDown = e.originalEvent.code == "KeyA";
});

$("#txtarea").keyup((e)=>{
  aDown = false;
});

$("#txtarea").click((e)=>{
  if (aDown) {
    console.log("A + Click!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Focus the textbox, hold down "A", and then click.<br>
<textarea id="txtarea"></textarea>
```

**Note:** On macOS, <kbd>control</kbd> + click is a shortcut for right-clicking, so your code won't fire. Consider listening to the `oncontextmenu` event and dealing with it if you care about macOS support - or perhaps changing your shortcut scheme.

Comment: Thanks this works, but I really wish we could nest it within each other(not in the way I did but something like that which works)

Answer (score 3):

You can simply check the [`ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/ctrlKey) property of the mouse event:

```js
$(function() {
  $('textarea').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
      console.log('clicked with ctrl');
    } else {
      console.log('clicked without ctrl');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>click me</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend setting up a global variable which holds the status of your ctrl key.

```
var ctrlDown=false;
```

Instead of simply listening for a keydown event, listen for a keyup event as well and update ctrldown accordingly.

```
$(textarea).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    ctrlDown = true;
  }
});
$(textarea).keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey) {
    ctrlDown = false;
  }
});
```

Now that you know that the ctrl key is actually pressed you can do a simple check like:

```
$(textarea).click(function(event) {
  if (ctrlDown) {
    console.log("catched")
  }
});
```

Comment: This works just as well when I'm going to use the letter keys, thanks.